# Trigonometry (sec x)

Tags: trigonometry

How $\sec (x)=\tan (x)+\frac{\cos (x)}{1+\sin (x)}$?

I'm doing some integral of sec x. Can I know how to derive it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Naturally you want everything to be in terms of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$, since they have simple identities. That is what you should simply do when you see these identities with many different trigonometric functions. So: $\sec x=\frac{1}{\cos x}$ and $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$. Then it's just algebraic manipulations and $\sin^2 x+ \cos^2 x=1$.

Answer (score 4):

What you want to prove: $$\sec (x)=\tan (x)+\frac{\cos (x)}{1+\sin (x)}$$ is the same as proving 
$$\begin{align} 
\frac{1}{\cos(x)} & = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x) } +\frac{\cos (x)}{1+\sin (x)}\tag{1}\\ \\
&= \dfrac{\sin(x)(1+\sin x) +\cos^2 x}{\cos(x)(1+\sin(x))}\tag{2}\\ \\
&= \frac{\sin x + \overbrace{\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x}^{\large =\,1}}{\cos(x)(1+\sin(x))}\tag{3}\\ \\
&= \frac{\sin x + 1}{\cos(x)(\sin(x) + 1)}\tag{4}\\ \\
&= \frac 1{\cos(x)}\tag{5}\end{align}$$

Now the identity has been verified. The right-hand side reduces to $\frac{1}{\cos(x)} = \sec(x)$, the left-hand side.

Answer (score 3):

$$\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x=(1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)\iff\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}=\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos x}$$